# Display 'SALE' tag before an image

Tags: html, css

I am looking to display a 'SALE' tag just before an image, I have tried to do this using the 'before' pseudo element however nothing seems to be displaying on the screen.

I am trying to create the 'SALE' tag inside a circle with black background.

Below is the code that I have used

```
<span class"bag-image">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images- 
amazon.com/images/I/71lDa7EbWSL._UY395_.jpg" class="image">
</span>

.bag-image::before{

background-color: #red;
content: 'SALE';
border-radius: 500px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

}
```

For visual reference:

[LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP5LQ.png)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgLPdp

Comment: Try `::after` instead of `::before`. If you use `::before`, SALE will be behind the image.

Comment: You might want to add an equal sign after class (class="bag-image"). Then it should work fine (apart from some further mark-up)

Comment: @JaviFernández doesn't seem to work, it places the SALE below the image. Please have a look at the link which i posted

Comment: @MoHaider you also need to position the image, relative to the parent. Add something like: `position: relative; top: 0px; text-align: center;`.

Comment: @MoHaider please provide a working snippet.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgLPdp

Comment: something like this may be? https://codepen.io/Tan007/pen/NVrVqW

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the bag-image class `position: relative;`
2. Make the bag-image:before `position: absolute;` and position it with top/left or margins and set the line-height to vertically center the SALE text.

You can give the pseudo-class a lower `z-index` so that only the top half is visible, e.g. `z-index: -1;`

You can use `margin-top: -2.5em; margin-left: 175px;` in the pseudo-code to position it.

```css
div.bag-image {
  display: inline-block;

  /* just so that we  can see in the example */
  margin-top: 3em;   
}

div.bag-image:before {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  content: 'SALE';
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
  margin-left: 175px;

  /* optionally make it a circle */
  border-radius: 9999px;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

/* just for clarity */
img.image {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="bag-image">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71lDa7EbWSL._UY395_.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary, you need to add the `position: relative` property to the `span`, and the `position: absolute` property to the `::after` element. Something like this:

```css
.bag-image {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.bag-image::after {
  background-color: red;
  content: 'SALE';
  border-radius: 500px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<span class="bag-image">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71lDa7EbWSL._UY395_.jpg" class="image">
</span>
```

Play with the `left` (and maybe the `top`) property to place the text in the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this. Also check the codepen.[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbWMRL#0)

```
<style>
.bag-image{
  text-align:center;
}
.bag-image::before{
content: 'SALE';
border-radius: 50px;
background: red;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
line-height: 100px;
color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code:**

your code `background-color: #red;` is the wrong to declared `#red` it's instant of only `red`.
 the sale is a position by my self parent relatively, you can learn about more position https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp .

here also write a shadow element related to some code for needed your answer.

maybe it solves your problem.

**=== Thanks ===**

```css
.bag-image {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.bag-image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bag-image::before{
  background-color: red;
  content: 'SALE';
  border-radius: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bag-image">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71lDa7EbWSL._UY395_.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```